# How to format array in ajax post

Tags: php, ajax, post, dialog

I have a dialog coded in php. On submit, I send the data back to the dialog to store via ajax (I don't want the dialog to close). This is mostly working but the format of the posted data isn't what I would like. Here is the ajax code

```
    $('#but1').click(function() {  
      var apply_to = $("input[name='group-apply']:checked").val();
      var el = document.getElementById('multi-selector');
      var selected = GetSelectValues(el);

      var data = [];
      data[0] = 'apply-to:'+ apply_to;
      data[1] = 'selected:' + selected;
      data = {data};         

       $.ajax({
            url : "example.php",
            type: "POST",
            data : data,
            success:function(result){
              $("#form-container").html(result);
            }
       });
    });
```

When the above is ran, the php in the dialog displays this

```
    Array
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => apply-to:Include
                [1] => selected:8,9,5,1
            )

    )
```

In order to use the above, I need to access it like this and then explode that to get the value.

```
    $_POST['data'][0]
```

I would like the data to display like this

```
    Array
    ( 
        [0] => apply-to:Include
        [1] => selected:8,9,5,1
    )
```

or, ideally:

```
    Array
    ( 
        [apply-to] => Include
        [selected] => 8,9,5,1
    )
```

Would someone please explain how to do that, if possible?

Comment: Just replace your `var data = [];` and 3 lines below to `var data = {apply_to: apply_to, selected: selected}`.

Answer (score 0):

In your php code  you could assing you $_POST['data'] to an array

```
$myArray = $_POST['data'];
```

then $myArray should be as

```
Array
( 
    [0] => apply-to:Include
    [1] => selected:8,9,5,1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it

```
$('#but1').click(function() {  
  var apply_to = $("input[name='group-apply']:checked").val();
  var el = document.getElementById('multi-selector');
  var selected = GetSelectValues(el);

  var data = [];
  data['apply-to'] = apply_to;
  data['selected'] = selected;
  data = {data};         

   $.ajax({
        url : "example.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : data,
        success:function(result){
          $("#form-container").html(result);
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `data` as object `{}`

To get value like

```
Array
( 
    [apply-to] => Include
    [selected] => 8,9,5,1
)
```

use

```
var data = {};
data['apply-to'] = apply_to;
data['selected'] = selected;
//data = {data}
```

and to get

```
Array
( 
    [0] => apply-to:Include
    [1] => selected:8,9,5,1
)
```

use

```
var data = {};
data[0] = 'apply-to:Include';
data[1] = 'selected:8,9,10';
//data = {data}
```